# Converting Javascript Bit Shift Code to VB.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, bit-shift

I have some data that I am scraping from a local device on my LAN. It uses javascript to format the data, but I need to perform the same formatting in VB.net. Here is an abbreviated version of the javascript:

```
var n = 0x740900;

alert(((n >>> 8) & 0xFF) + 1);
//result is 10

n = 0x740a00;

alert(((n >>> 8) & 0xFF) + 1);
//result is 11
```

Essentially, I need to feed a variable (n in this case) into the calculation, and then I am returned a value.

From my research, the >>> is a zero-fill right shift operator. I've been trying to replicate it in VB.net, but the >>> operator isn't available.

Any ideas how I can replicate this in VB.net?

Comment: Is it just >> ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83.aspx

Comment: May I know what type of number is in the `var`

Comment: It's a hex number that has the month and the year in it. The operation I am attempting extracts the month (10 is for October, 11 is for November, etc)

Comment: its too late hehe already have the code but the other get it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim n As UInteger = &H740900
Console.WriteLine(((n >> 8) And &HFF) + 1)
'result is 10
n = &H740A00
Console.WriteLine(((n >> 8) And &HFF) + 1)
Console.ReadKey()
'result is 11
```

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick. The "And" was throwing me off as well. Thanks so much!